# I do not understand how to write the function :((

Tags: javascript, arrays, concatenation, chaining, parseint

What is the difference between a named function and an anonymous function?

Comment: Your loop is fine. The statement below it doesn't do anything: you just read `innerHTML` and discard it. You'd want to assign something to it instead.

Answer (score 2):

You need to do two things, You have to assign a value to this `document.getElementById("gradeInput").innerHTML` & secondly depending on the condition you may like to show content of array as a string for that use `join` with comma delimiter  or sum the values in the array.

```js
var grades = [];
var i;
for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  grades.push(Number(prompt("Enter your grades:" + (i + 1))));
}
document.getElementById("gradeInput").innerHTML = grades.join(',')
```

```html
<div id='gradeInput'>
```

If you wnat to show the summation of the input from prompt then instead of initializing `grades` initialize it with `0`. Then add the input from prompt to this

```js
var grades = 0;
var i;
for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  grades += Number(prompt("Enter your grades:" + (i + 1)));
}
document.getElementById("gradeInput").innerHTML = grades;
```

```html
<div id='gradeInput'>
```

Comment: Oh I like this a lot!! Thank you! Is there a way to find the averages of the input values?

Comment: Yes add all the values the array then divide it by the array lenght

Comment: var total = 0;
     for (var i = 0; i < grades.length; i++) {
     total += grades[i];
        }
     var avg = total / grades.length;

Answer (score 0):

You can find the Average using this method.

```
   var sum=0;

   grades.forEach(calculateAverage);
    function calculateAverage(values) {
        sum+= values;
        var avg = sum/grades.length;
        document.getElementById("Average").innerHTML ="Average Grade:</br>" + avg;

    }

   <div id="Average"></div>
```